# Set the default template filter for the context_processor in flask

Tags: python, flask

In my flask app i have these codes:

```py
from __main__ import app

@app.context_processor
def breakline():
    return { 'break': '<br>' }
```

How to use in html format is as follows:

```html
{{ break }}
```

The above code works but there is a problem; A `safe` filter is needed to detect `<br>`; But I *do not want* to be added in html format every time like this:

```html
{{ break | safe }}
```

I want this `safe` filter to be applied automatically and no longer need to be used in the html page. Is such a thing possible?

*This is just an example and I do not just want to be able to create a `<br>`. I want to know if a filter can be added to a context_processor or not.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mark your html code as safe by using [Markup](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Markup).

```
from flask import Markup

@app.context_processor
def breakline():
    return { 'break': Markup('<br>') }
```